# Angular 2 nested routing issue (Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-routing, nested-routes

I have parent route `/details` which show `employee list in table`. I want to open each `employee details` below its `employee row` So only one employee details should be visible at a time just below its row.

In short want to create nested expandable table grid using `Angular routing`.

I have created routing structure and code [like this(stackblitz project)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-nesting-issue).
This `throws error` when tried to revisit the `route` as

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null
```

Found hard to explain so added `GIF` below:

[image]

If I removed `*ngIf`condition from `details.component.html Line : 20`

```
<td colspan="2" *ngIf="employee.id === selectedEmployeeId">
```

Then `routing works` but it opens all the `router outlet` at same time.

I have tried many ways but not succeeded, Can anyone please provide the suggestion or update the [sample project code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-nesting-issue).

References:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19374
[Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789867/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-component-of-null)